# (ASP classic) Stop/Block execution of rest of code without interrupt Javascript execution

Tags: asp-classic, session, merge

I am running in an issue similar to the one in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279066/looking-for-a-hack-to-prevent-rewriting-an-app-without-using-session-variables) and I'm getting short of ideas so I would really appreciate any help !

Here's the thing : 
 We have an ASP application that uses session variables and has to deal with session merging due to multitabs (IE8).

After many many many tries, I've came to the following implementation :

1. I'm setting an ID to each browser's TAB (I'm using the [sessionStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197062%28VS.85%29.aspx#_session) for that) on client-side.
2. In order to make it available from server-side (since I could not find any other way) I'm saving it in a cookie and reloading the page.
3. Finally on my ASP pages, I'm getting this ID from the cookie and using it as prefix of all the sessions variables on the application.

Here's a short example

Javascript (Inserted at the very beginning of every asp files)

```
    LoadJs();

    // Cookie and TabID handler
    function LoadJs()
    {
        if (getInternetExplorerVersion() <= 6)
        {
            //alert("Exit..... old browser version : " + getInternetExplorerVersion());
            return;
        }

        if (sessionStorage.TabID)
        {
            // Check value in cookie 
            var tabIdinCookie = readCookie("tabid");

            // if ID in cookie not the same as ID in session update cookie and
            // refresh the page to update values in server-side
            if(!tabIdinCookie || (tabIdinCookie && tabIdinCookie != sessionStorage.TabID)) 
            {
                createCookie("tabid",sessionStorage.TabID);
                ReloadPage();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Create random ID
            var currentTime = new Date();    
            sessionStorage.TabID = currentTime.getTime();
            // Save ID to cookie
            createCookie("tabid",sessionStorage.TabID);
            createCookie("usingIE8",true,1);

            // Refresh the page to make it available from server-side
            ReloadPage();

         }
         return true;
    }

    // Redirect to the same page to refresh data at server-side
    function ReloadPage()
    {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
```

---

Then, the ASP code :

```
<%
   Dim Nm 
   Nm=""


response.Write("<br>Reading from cookie....")

   if (Request.cookies("usingIE8") <> "" )then
        if (Request.cookies("tabid") = "") then
            'response.Write("<br>No cookie")
            'response.flush() 
            ' WHAT TO DO HERE ????
        else
            Response.Write("<br>Cookie FOUND<br>")
            Nm = Request.cookies("tabid")
        end if
   end if 




if (Session(Nm + "LogonTime")="") then
    Response.Write("<br><b>Updating session</b><br>")
    Session(Nm + "LogonTime") = Now
    UpdateInDB(Session(Nm + "LogonTime"))
    ' Do other stuffs
end if
```

%>

---

I was pretty proud about finally getting a workaround to the issue, but I realized that when a page do a post action, all code ASP is rendered (with the wrong prefix-ID) and executed (database operations included) before right TabID can be updated on the cookie and page can be reloaded by javascript. I mean that all my page code is being executed twice, once before and once again after the refresh... :-|

Does anyone think it could be possible to implement smthg like a Response.End() to prevent the rest of the code ASP to execute if I can identify I have to refresh the page without killing at the same time the javascript execution ? Or to wait for all javascript execution before any other action on the page ?

I'm stuck here and it make me cry to have to stop here ! There must be a solution... If I can fin a fix, it would be to be applied to many ASP (3.0) applications that won't be upgraded to ASP.NET before at least 3 or 5 years.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Another approach that would make me happy if possible would be to catch each request to update the cookie before execution of ASP script on the page !! :-) .... anyone ?

Comment: It means there's nothing else to do ? 
..... :'(

Answer (score 0):

i do not get why you all do this but instead of reloading a whole page i would use ajax to set the session variables?

ok for example with jquery:

```
// AJAX Request
$.post("session.asp", { act: "setSession", varName: "myVar", varValue: "myVal" },
  function(data) {
    alert("new Session value: " + data);
});
```

then on session.asp:

```
if request.form("act") = "setSession" then
    session(request.form("varName")) = request.form("varValue")
    ' now you have the new value in Session:
    ' 
    response.write Session("myVar")
end if
```

hope this helps

Comment: Hi ulluoink, thanks for your reply.... 
It could be an interesting approach but I must confess I have no idea how could I achive it ... I can image using jQuery for instance, but then how could I update the session variable ? I would be manipulating an ASP (not .NET ) session ... Do you think it could be possible ?